# Mysql - Insert based on other table where condition - ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: mysql, insert, duplicates

**UPDATE**

**I found the answer and provided below**

Dear All,

I want to insert into a table 
1) Based on condition on other table
2) and using ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE on the first table.

The following query I wrote which is syntactically wrong  . Could you please help me on the correct query for this ?

```
INSERT INTO my_all_count (type,code,count) values ( 0,1,1) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count = count + 1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( 
  select 1 from my_reg_count 
  where country_code=CurrCountry and type=0 and code=0);
```

here 
1) I want to insert into table my_all_count
2) type,code is a key and if it exists increasing county by 1 
3) Insert only when it is not exists in my_reg_count

Thanks for your help

Regards

Kiran

Comment: So you want to insert, update and not insert at the same time. Nice. Stored procedure, or handle outside mysql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution and here is the answer

```
INSERT INTO my_all_count (type,code,count) 
    select 0,0,1 from dual WHERE NOT EXISTS ( 
         select * from my_reg_count where country_code=CurrCountry 
          and type=0 and code=0) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count = count + 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this will work, but I *am* sure the `ON DUPLICATE KEY` clause should be after the `WHERE` clause:

```
INSERT INTO my_all_count (type,code,count) values (0,1,1) 
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( 
  select 1 from my_reg_count 
  where country_code=CurrCountry and type=0 and code=0)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count = count + 1;
```

Comment: Thanks Galz for your response . Even with out using Duplicate Key Update , it says it is showing syntax error at where clause . I mean even the following insert statement is wrong too  INSERT INTO my_all_count (type,code,count) values (0,1,1) 
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( 
  select 1 from my_reg_count 
  where country_code=CurrCountry and type=0 and code=0)

Comment: @Bujji - can you explain the logic behind this WHERE? Which tables hold the columns country_code and CurrCountry? This can probably be re-written with a JOIN...

Comment: Thanks Galz for your quick response . This my_reg_count has count of users registered at Country level . I mean It is like this USA-10, BRAZIL-20 , Canada-30 ... and my_all_count will count the total number of countries it is total 3 in this case . I think I found the solution now . Here is the code if it works I will update my question   INSERT INTO my_all_count (type,code,count) select 0,0,1 from dual  
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( select * from my_reg_count where country_code=CurrCountry and type=0 and code=0)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count = count + 1;

Comment: @Bujji - sounds like you needed the SELECT to apply the WHERE. Let me know if it worked or if you need anymore help

Comment: I just tested it and It is working fine .Thanks a lot for giving me inputs